# Munin: Is it possible to recover lost graphs?

Tags: graph, munin

I'm not extremely familiar with how munin works, so I apologize if this is obvious.

I've been using munin for a couple of my projects now and I've run into this twice where I will lose all my munin graphs that were generated from past events. This just happened to me this afternoon. Now, I only have a track record of all system events since this afternoon.

Are these graphs recoverable? Is there data stored somewhere thats used to generate these graphs?

If its unrecoverable, I would like to know what could possibly have caused this to occur.  Granted, each time this has happened, I was messing w/ my munin config settings. For this case, I was adding new servers to be logged by munin...I dont see how doing that would cause munin to lose all data on my other servers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data is generated from .rrd databases which are updated during 'munin-update' (usually called from 'munin-cron'). You can find those files in the directory specified by 'dbdir' in munin.conf (/var/db/munin on my site). If your graphs only show events since this afternoon, my guess is that the .rrd files got deleted/recreated/corrupted. You should be able to restore them from backup and then call 'munin-graph' and 'munin-html'. See the respective man-pages for those commands.